# how to center the calender in bootstrap dateTimePicker

Tags: date, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have added the date time picker but I can't center every thing in the calender?

[the fault one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHTxS.png)

[The right one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TwWe.png)

This is the html code

```
<div class="form-group" id="dateTimePickerContainer">
   <label>
     <input name="datetimepicker" type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker'/>
   </label>
</div>
```

And this is the Jquery code

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
```

Comment: add your effort  or code here please. [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the problem that the css file was not included in the project.
So I had to download the css and included it in the bootstrap files.
Anyone can download it from [here](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/tree/master/build/css).
 a